# Update JSON value in child component sent by parent component LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, child-to-parent, parent-to-child

Im passing a JSON from parent component to child component in LWC and I want to update the JSON in child component how can I do that?
I think @api decorator is the cause that the JSON cannot be updates in the child component.

Sample code
parent.js

```
@api Json = [{"ID":1,
             "Name":"test"}];
```

parent.html

```
<template>
<c-child Json={Json}></c-child>
</template>
```

child.js

```
@api Json

connectedcallback(){
Json[0].Name = "test101";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct - it's the `api` decorator. This makes the property read-only

To get around, use a getter/setter to do this:

```
_json;
@api
get Json() {
  return this._json;
}
set Json(value) {
  this._json = value;
}

connectedcallback(){
  this._json[0].Name = "test101";
}
```